# Yii2 как в конфиге приложения добавить нужные response headers

Tags: yii

Необходимо на уровне всего приложения для всех ендпоинтов добавить в response нужные headers.

Как это можно сделать централизованно на уровне всего приложения?

Answer (score 0):

Вдруг кому то понадобиться

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'response' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\Response',
            'on beforeSend' => function ($event) {
                // Получаем объект ответа
                $response = $event->sender;

                // Устанавливаем заголовки
                $response->headers->set('X-My-Header', 'My Header Value');
                $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
                // и так далее...

                // Пример: Установка заголовка Content-Type
                $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

                // Пример: Установка заголовка Access-Control-Allow-Origin
                $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            },
        ],
    ],
    // остальная конфигурация вашего приложения...
];
```